# Surefire launch ignores TestWatcher JUnit Rule

Tags: junit, automated-tests, maven-surefire-plugin

I have this rule, which applies to all my tests:

```
protected String testName = "";

@Rule
public TestWatcher watcher = new TestWatcher() {
    public void starting(Description description) {
        testName = description.getMethodName();
    }
};
```

It gets executed when I launch my tests with vanilla JUnit. However, when I launch my tests with Surefire (with Maven Surefire Plugin), it is not executed --> `testName` remains an empty string.

Here is the part of my POM when I declare Maven Surefire Plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.14</version>
  <configuration>
    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    <argLine>javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
    </argLine>
    <properties>
      <property>
      <name>listener</name>
      <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
    <parallel>classes</parallel>
    <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
    <threadCount>80</threadCount>
    <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.